# ubuntu 16.04. How to install samba with python 3.7?

Tags: 16.04, server, python, samba

One day i've installed python 3.7 from sources on Ubuntu 16.04. After first reboot samba shares disappear. Please help me to install samba with python3.7.

```
$ sudo apt install samba

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 samba : Depends: python-dnspython but it is not going to be installed
         Depends: python-samba but it is not going to be installed
         Depends: samba-common-bin (= 2:4.3.11+dfsg-0ubuntu0.16.04.17) but it is not going to be installed
         Depends: python (< 2.8) but 3.7.0-1 is to be installed
         Depends: samba-libs (= 2:4.3.11+dfsg-0ubuntu0.16.04.17) but it is not going to be installed
         Recommends: samba-dsdb-modules but it is not going to be installed
         Recommends: samba-vfs-modules but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Comment: Run `sudo apt install -f`

Comment: `$ sudo apt install -f


Reading package lists... Done

Building dependency tree

Reading state information... Done

0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.`

Comment: Now try again to install it!

Comment: No. I've tried. The error is the same as I described in the question.

Comment: Please run `sudo dpkg --configure -a` and try again if no errors!

Comment: Thank You. But nothing was happened. No errors, and all after is the same. I think, I will delete a python 3.7. But make uninstall does not working.

Comment: I removed only two symbolic links at /usr/local/bin: `python3` and `python3-config` and problem was resolved!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I removed only two symbolic links at /usr/local/bin: `python3` and `python3-config` and problem was resolved!